# How can I get students position based on their total score

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

This code is just giving me 1 as the position of all my students. I would like the students to have their position based on their total. If their is a tie in total, it should be able to handle that too. Any help will be highly appreciated
Below is my code

```
$getStudPosition=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT  sum(sr.total) AS gtot FROM  student_result sr WHERE   sr.studentId='$id' ORDER BY resId DESC");
        while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($getStudPosition)) 
        {
            $students = array($gTotal=$r['gtot']);// convert to array
            $pos = $real_pos = 0;
            $prev_score = -1;
          foreach ($students as $exam_n => $score) 
            {
              $real_pos += 1;
              $pos = ($prev_score != $score) ? $real_pos: $pos;
              $prev_score = $score;
            }
            $average = $score/$totSubject; //getting students average
        }
```

[image: This is the screenshot of my output]

I'm running 10.4.18 version of MariaDB.

Comment: from where re you getting student name, grand total, average and position? Is this data required from same query. Please share your table structure with create script and sample data with insert script. Also, let me know which version of mysql you are using.

Comment: [some ideas](https://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=460&m=0) that show window functions are an easy approach if you have a sufficient mysql-8.0 or mariadb-10.2+ version.

Comment: Student name, Grand Total are fetched from the database, average is the total of each students grand total/(total subject) which is also from the database. The position is what I'm trying to get based on the Grand Total. I'm running 10.4.18 version of MariaDB

Comment: You can perhaps use ORDER BY. I don't think there is a function that does this.

Comment: You use `WHERE sr.studentId='$id'` which selects ONE student - of course the position is 1.

Comment: studentId='$id' ORDER ... please read about SQL Injections

Comment: @Akina I got your point. Do you have any idea of how to fetch multiple students and maintain a different position, please?

Comment: please edit your question to add (as text, not an image) output of `show create table student_result;`

Comment: you want ties handled, but *how* do you want them handled?  if totals are 100, 90, 90, 80, are those positions 1, 2, 2, 3 or 1, 2, 2, 4 or something else?

Comment: Please provide: 1) Table structure (the output for `SHOW CREATE TABLE student_result;`); 2) MySQL version (the output for `SELECT VERSION();`). Also answer to the @ysth's question from previous comment.

Comment: @ysth if you have 100, 90, 90, 80 the tie should be handled like 1, 2, 2, 3. Thanks

Comment: and your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get the position for the students one at a time, inside a loop?  Getting the position for all of them at once is going to be much more efficient.  To do this, you simply need to use https://mariadb.com/kb/en/rank/.  It's hard to give a more detailed answer without the information we've asked for.